# Elastic Beanstalk takes 40 minutes to deploy, what did I did wrong?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've been using AWS for almost a year now and for some reason for a month or so every time I want to deploy a new version of a web application into Elastic Beanstalk (EB) it takes about 40 minutes, It's making the development imposible. Help!

I currently only have 1 instance running and remove the batch but nothing seem to change.

Comment: Answering this would require very much information about the deployment, your aws environment, etc.  But I'll give you one thought: you shouldn't need to push your code to EB while developing, only when you're ready to make a release.   If your development cycle is code->deploy->test, get the app running locally so you can code->test->code->test->...->deploy instead.

Comment: How is your configuration for **Rolling updates and deployments**? Is the deployment policy set to **Rolling** or **Immutable**? You need to check the Event Log while the deployment is running in order to have a better understanding of what is causing the issue.  As @DanFarrell said in my previous comment you should be deploying changes to the server after you have finalised the coding on your local/dev machine